# I have two identical TeamViewer IDs on my 2 MacBooks

Tags: teamviewer

I have two identical ID on my 2 MacBooks. When I tried to remote control the other Mac, TeamViewer tells me I am entering the ID of my own computer.

But why did TeamViewer give me two identical IDs? How can I solve it

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is an issue for cloned machines.
Removing the .plist file should clear it & set up a fresh UUID

The file is at 
`~/Library/Preferences/com.teamviewer.TeamViewer.plist`
…however there may be multiple files, depending on how many versions of TeamViewer you've ever had installed. My machine has 6 different files & I couldn't be certain which to remove. I'd zip or trash them all & just start afresh.

Quit TeamViewer beforehand & reboot afterwards, just to make sure you get a clean start.

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't happen and I don't know how the original ones are "calculated", but last time I used it, I'm pretty sure there's been a link under the ID to get a new one.

Comment: I think thats because I clone a mac to another. but there is no solution to solve it

Comment: @poc That sounds really weird. Have you tried contacting their support team? This sounds like a massive bug to me (potential security issue as well), considering the actual hardware isn't identical.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this on this OS, but it works on Windows and I am confident it would work the same elsewhere.

You are trying to create an image of the PC to be loaded on a bunch of different PCs later on, and you would like the TV ID to be unique for every new image load?

Solution:

Install, set up, do what ever you need without installing the TV. Disconnect your PC from the network (the TV needs to contact its server to obtain ID). Install the TV, then create image/clone.

When you load this clone on another computer, the TV will ask the server for ID for the first time and receive a unique one.

If you have a system that has a TV and you need to clone this one, uninstall the TV completely, disconnect from the network, and install again with no Internet. Then create the clone.